# vim opening file in left split screen

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When i open a file from nerdtree or vimfiler, the file is opening in left slipt screen and nerdtree/vimfiler jumps to right split screen..i got this problem after replacing vundle with neobundle eventhough neobundle has nothing to do with nerdtree/vimfiler..here is my vimrc file
https://github.com/rajanand02/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

vim before opening a file
[image: vim before opening a file]

vim after opening a file from startify or from vimfiler/nerdtree
[image: after opening a file from startify or from vimfiler/nerdtree]

these are the settings releated to nerdtree/vimfiler

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTreeTabsOpen 
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTreeMirror
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p

let g:vimfiler_as_default_explorer = 1
autocmd VimEnter * VimFilerExplorer
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by removing Tiled Window Manager Plugin [dwm.vim](https://github.com/spolu/dwm.vim)..i had this plugin before migrating from Vundle to NeoBundle but When i update vimrc with NeoBundle something went wrong with this plugin..i figured this by inlcuding all the plugins one by one..

Answer (score 1):

You can swicth two existing windows with `<C-w>x` with `x` like e`x`change.

Comment: even if i switch windows it will work properly until i open another file..as soon as i open a new file the above problem occurs..